Calculate Bell polynomial $B_{l,k}(x, x^2, x^3, \ldots,x^{l-k+1})$.
I am trying to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{l}({-}1)^{k{-}1}(k{-}1)!B_{l,k}(x,x^{2},\ldots ,x^{{l-k+1}}) = 0$$
where
$B_{l,k}(x_1,x_{2},\ldots ,x_{{l-k+1}})$ is the partial (or incomplete) Bell polynomial.
Now, I know that the exponents in the Bell polynomial all sum to $l$, so in essence I have to show that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{l} ({-}1)^{k{-}1} (k{-}1)! \sum \prod_{i=1}^{{l-k+1}}{\frac{1}{(i!)^{j_{i}}j_{i}!}} = 0,
\end{equation}
where the inner sum is over all sequences $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_{{l-k+1}}$ of non-negative integers satisfying ${ j_{1}{+}j_{2}{+}\cdots{ +}j_{{l-k+1}}=k,}$ and ${\sum_{m=1}^{{l-k+1}}mj_{m}=l.}$
However, I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

You maybe can use the derivative representation of your Bell polynomials via the Faa di Bruno formula

@ТymaGaidash, thanks for this! I had not thought about using the en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula. Possible solution below. The credit goes to you.

Using the Faa di Bruno formula as suggested by @TymaGaidash, let $f(x) = \log x$ and $g(x)=\exp{(x)}$. Then the LHS is zero ($m$th derivative of 1) and the RHS is
\begin{equation}
\exp{(x)}\sum_{k=1}^{l} \frac{({-}1)^{k{-}1} (k{-}1)!}{\exp{(kx)}} \sum \prod_{i=1}^{{l-k+1}}{\frac{1}{(i!)^{j_{i}}j_{i}!}} = 0,
\end{equation}
where the inner sum is over all sequences $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_{{l-k+1}}$ of non-negative integers satisfying ${ j_{1}{+}j_{2}{+}\cdots{ +}j_{{l-k+1}}=k,}$ and ${\sum_{m=1}^{{l-k+1}}mj_{m}=l.}$
Evaluated at $x=0$, the result follows.
